# Total probability theorem visualisation

Tags: probability

I recently started doing this topic but I am having trouble identifying the sample sample space and solving it .I will give u an example in case

Eg-When a missile is fired from a ship,the probability that it is intercepted is 1/3.The probability that the missile hits the targer ,given it is not intercepted is 3/4.If three missile are fired indpendently from ahip,the probability that all three hits the target.

My analysis-Basically calculating probability of the missile hitting one target and multiplying it to itself three times will give me the probability.But I can't visualise the sample space and also the events that are mutually exclusive and exhaustive.any help

Comment: Well, can you compute the probability that a single missile hits the target?  From there, I assume you are meant to assume independence (though that seems somewhat unphysical).

Comment: I can do that if i know which events are mutually exclusive and also if i can visualise the sample space

Comment: Well..."being intercepted" and "not being intercepted" are mutually exclusive, yes?

Comment: YEAH!That helps a lot but how can i visualise the sample space for this...can u help me for dat

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to visualize. For each missile only three things can happen:  The missile is intercepted, the missile is not intercepted but misses, the missile is not intercepted and hits.  Those three events are mutually exclusive (clearly) and exhaustive.

Comment: Is this the sample space of the experiment

Comment: Well, for a single missile, sure.

Comment: thanx it helps a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suitable sample space would be the results of the three missile launches: intercept, miss, or hit.  $\{{\sf I, M, H}\}^3$ is an acceptable representation for this.   However, you hardly need to use this.

The results for a particular missile launch are *mutually exclusive and exhaustive* events, since a launched missile may either be exactly one of intercepted, miss, or hit; not anything else, and not any combination.

The three launch results are pairwise independent events, since the results for any two particular missiles are presented as having no influence on each other.

Your favoured event is $\{({\sf H,H,H})\}$ and indeed is $\mathbb P\{({\sf H,H,H})\}= {(\tfrac 23\tfrac 34)}^3$, which comes from the probabilities given and the pairwise independence between the results for different missiles. (Also the definition of conditional probability).

Comment: thanx it helps a lot but I have a doubt.You said it's not necessary to find sample space but isn't it imp for the question?

Comment: Unless there is more to the question than shown, no; it is a diversion.